# How to solve symbolic equation system in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, sympy, equation

I am new from MATLAB to Python. I have now problem with solve equation system in Python. For example, in Matlab

```
R = solve( a1*[x1; x2] == [y1;y2], ...  
           a2*[x3; x4] == [y3;y4], ...
           a3*[x5; x6] == [y5;y6], ... 
           x2 == y3, x3 == y2, ...        
           x4 == y5, x5 == y4, ... 
           [    x2 x3 x4 x5    ...   
             y1 y2 y3 y4 y5 y6]...   % unknown
          );
y1 = simplify(R.y1);
y10 = simplify(R.y10);
```

a1..a5 are coefficient  y1 y10 are what I need to solve and they should be symbolic expression after solve. How to do this in Python?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

NumPy has no concept of symbolic solutions. You can use SymPy as follows:

```
from sympy import *
a1, a2, a3 = 3, 4, 5   #   known coefficients, they could be symbols too
x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6 = symbols('x1:7')
y1, y2, y3, y4, y5, y6 = symbols('y1:7')
eqns = [a1*x1 - y1, a1*x2 - y2, a2*x3 - y3, a2*x4 - y4, a3*x5 - y5, a3*x6 - y6, 
        x2 - y3, x3 - y2, x4 - y5, x5 - y4]
linsolve(eqns, [x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, y1, y2, y3, y4, y5, y6])
```

The output is `{(y1/3, 0, 0, 0, 0, y6/5, y1, 0, 0, 0, 0, y6)}` indicating that most of variables must be 0, x1 must be y1/3, x5 must be y6/6, and the variables y1, y2 can be whataver.

The above uses [`linsolve`](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/solveset.html#sympy.solvers.solveset.linsolve) because the system is linear in each of the unknowns. Other [solvers](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/solvers.html) are available for nonlinear equations.

Note that equations can be entered as either `lhs - rhs` (as I did above) or `Eq(lhs, rhs)`. Not as `lhs == rhs` which would immediately evaluate to False in Python.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I see you expanded the Matrix in equations. How to keep them in Matrix?  Is linsolve(a1*matrix([[x1],[y1]])....) the right way?

Comment: As the linsolve documentation says, either matrix form or list form is acceptable. But not a mix of both like in your example. You'll need to do something in Python to bring the equations to the form that linsolve understands.

Comment: If a1,a2, a3 are 2x2-Matrix und have members with complex expression, how can we solve it. I have tryied by myself over 7 hours, but not solved jet /0/