# symbolic solution of linear equations using Sympy

Tags: python, python-3.x, sympy

Basically I have [5x5][5x1]=[0] and would like to have the symbolic expression of the solution.

Here is my code.

```
from sympy import symbols, solve
gm1, gm2, gm4                   = symbols(['gm1', 'gm2', 'gm4'])
gds1, gds2, gds3, gds4, gds5    = symbols(['gds1', 'gds2', 'gds3', 'gds4', 'gds5'])
s                               = symbols(['s'])
Cd, CF , Cin, Ct                = symbols(['Cd', 'CF', 'Cin', 'Ct'])
K                               = symbols(['K'])
vb, vc, ve, vout, iin           = symbols(['vb', 'vc', 've', 'vout', 'iin'])

sol = solve([-(gds1+gds3+(s*Cd))*vb + (gm1+gds1)*ve + -gm1*vout, \
          -gm4*vb + (gds4-gds2-(s*Cin)-(s*CF))*vc + (gds2+gm2)*ve + s*CF*vout + iin, \
        gds1*vb + gds2*vc + (-(s*Ct)-gds5-gds1-gm1-gm2-gds2)*ve + gm1*vout, \
        K*vc + vout], [vout])
print(sol)
```

but, I got this error

```
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'Symbol'
```

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50047755/how-to-solve-symbolic-equation-system-in-python), symbolic multiplication seems working just fine.

I am not sure whether I describe my problem in a way that does not comply with Sympy or something else.

What did I miss here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the assignment of the single symbols `s` and `K`.  If instead you do:

```
s, K = symbols(['s', 'K'])
```

Or:

```
s = symbols('s')
K = symbols('K')
```

Whether you get the right answer or not is another matter :)

Comment: Thanks! it solves the error, the code returns nothing though. Now I am confuse whether to accept your answer as the correct one :)

Comment: The answer clearly solves and explains the question posed. Why wouldn't you accept it? Maybe the answer is too trivial? In that case, also the question was too trivial.  Moreover, sympy gives the correct answer that there aren't solutions writable as an expression for `vout` that satisfy all the equations.

Comment: I think there is a closed form solution for vout. Anyway, I think you are right. it answers the and solves the problem. regarding Sympy does not return answer is another issue.

Comment: The better fix is to use e.g. `symbols("k")` and `symbols("s, K")` i.e. use a single string with spaces and/or commas. You can get a nontrivial answer from solve if you specify 4 unknowns for the system of 4 equations (if `vout` is the only unknown then the system is almost certainly inconsistent).

Answer (score 1):

When you pass a list to `symbols` you get a list back. You can unpack that like `[s] = symbols(['s'])` or you can just pass a string of space or comma separated strings like `x, y = symbols('x y')` or `x, y = symbols(','.join(['x', 'y'])`.

If you select `manual=True` you will get a solution `vout=K*vc` which sets the 4th equation to 0. But that was almost obvious, right? And you didn't need the other 3 equations to tell you that. So go ahead and pick up to 3 other variables for which you want to solve. There are lots of possibilities:

```
>>> from sympy.functions.combinatorial.numbers import nC
>>> allsym = Tuple(*eqs).free_symbols
>>> nfree = len(allsym) - 1  # always take vout
>>> print(nC(nfree, 3))  # want 3 others
816
```

For example, selecting `(vout, gds4, gm1, gds5)` gives a solution of

```
[{gds4: (CF*K*s*vc + CF*s*vc + Cin*s*vc + gds2*vc -
         gds2*ve - gm2*ve + gm4*vb - iin)/vc, 
  gm1: (Cd*s*vb + gds1*vb - gds1*ve + gds3*vb)/(K*vc + ve), 
  gds5: -(Cd*s*vb + Ct*s*ve - gds2*vc + gds2*ve + gds3*vb + gm2*ve)/ve, 
  vout: -K*vc}]
```